# Able to locate frame with selenium, but doesn't work with Junit Cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I am able to locate a frame using a selenium java program. The following code runs successfully:

```
public static void TestCase() throws IOException, InterruptedException{ 


                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
                driver.manage().window().maximize();  
                driver.get("website"); 


                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys(userName);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("password");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='session_link']")).click();    


                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app_236']/a")).click(); //Click a link on the page

                driver.switchTo().frame("iframe100-100"); //Switch to a frame within the new page

                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='yui-gen0']/li[2]/div")).click(); //Click element within the frame
}
```

But if I run the same code using a Cucumber Junit maven project, the program is not able to locate the frame.

```
@Given("^I log into website$")
    public void log_in()
    {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        driver.manage().window().maximize();  
        driver.get("website"); 

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys(userName);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='session_link']")).click();    

    }

@When("^I select the link from homepage$")
    public void select_link() throws InterruptedException
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app_236']/a")).click();       
    }

@Then("^I should see something$")
    public void click_element_within_frame()
    {
        driver.switchTo().frame("iframe100-100"); //Switch to a frame within the new page

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='yui-gen0']/li[2]/div")).click(); //Click element within the frame
}
```

Error message :

31morg.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame: iframe100-100

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Chances are the digits in `iframe100-100` are dynamic. Same thing probably for `app_236` and `yui-gen0`. Those xpaths look nasty! Why not use something more legible like `By.id("username")`?

Comment: Thanks @SiKing. Turns out the same iframe takes different numbers for different users who login ( as you said - dynamic ). And there was nothing else unique that I could identify the iframe with. So I tried to find it by index. I tried from 0 - 3 till the element inside it was clicked. Turns out, the index is 2.